# CSS Web fonts how to use it with use of @font-face its not working

Tags: html, css

this is my stylesheet for web font

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
src: url('bebasneue-webfont.eot');
src: url('bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('bebasneue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

and me use that font like this

```
.men_tp{
        color: #d1d3d5; 
        float: left; 
        font-family:"bebas_neueregular",Arial; 
        font-size:22px;
         }
```

its working fine in my machine because i have those fonts but that font not applying for other hosts even i placed those font src in same area were i placed that CSS file.Help me Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your CSS line to the following:

```
.men_tp {
    color: #d1d3d5;
    float: left;
    font-family: bebas_neueregular, Arial;
    font-size:22px;
}
```

(The line breaks have only been inserted to make it easier to read on this page.)

You've declared the new font as having name "bebas-neueregular" in your @font-face block, so you need to use that in your CSS declaration for the `.men_tp` style.

Comment: Oh, also make sure to check that font-face has not been disabled in the other browsers. I've disabled font-face in my Firefox browser because the font rendering engine was never designed to receive content from across a network, so I doubt it has been written with security in mind.